# Unity 3d main camera LookAt is not rotating on x axis

Tags: unity-game-engine

Am developing a follow target camera, it's working fine but when the vehicle(Target) is on slope, the camera is not rotating to show the full vehicle.

```
void LateUpdate()
    {

        if (car1.controlled && Camera.main != null)
        {
            float speedFactor = Mathf.Clamp01(target.root.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude / 20.0f);
            if (speedFactor < 0.01f)
                speedFactor = 0.01f;

            Camera.main.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(40, 65, speedFactor);

            float currentDistance = Mathf.Lerp(13.5f, 8.5f, speedFactor);

            currentVelocity = currentVelocity.normalized;

            Vector3 newTargetPosition = target.position + Vector3.up * height;
            Vector3 newPosition = newTargetPosition - ((currentVelocity * currentDistance));
            newPosition.y = newTargetPosition.y;

            Vector3 targetDirection = newPosition - newTargetPosition;
            if (Physics.Raycast(newTargetPosition, targetDirection, out hit, currentDistance, raycastLayers))
                newPosition = hit.point;

            Camera.main.transform.position = newPosition;   
            Camera.main.transform.LookAt(newTargetPosition);    
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

LookAt is going to set the camera rotation to be looking straight at the `newTargetPosition`. It doesn't actually moves the camera up, it simply rotates it to look at the vehicule. You should modify your code so the camera moves up when the vehicule goes down a slope and then make it look at the vehicule.

Comment: In addition to this, it might make sense to lock the camera at a specific height above the vehicle and to the ground. If the camera always elevates or descends (smoothly) to that height + distance to the vehicle. Additionally, you may want to allow the camera to rotate, such as when turning the vehicle, where the camera slowly returns to the rear position of the vehicle, but not immediately as the car is turning.